# Python ImportError loading module within subfolder

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have the following structure

```
abc/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    tests/
       __init__.py
       test.py
```

in `test.py`, I am getting an `ImportError` for

```
#test.py
import abc.settings
```

Comment: You have to add the main directory (where `abc` is in), to your `sys.path`

Comment: @BlackVegetable oh, so if I move tests folder to the same level as abc then it should work

Comment: My comment was slightly mistaken.  Look to @Wolph for the correct answer.

Comment: If you feel like getting your hands dirty, you can try out this module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html

Comment: That seems like an odd arrangement for tests. See e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/ for a handy guide to structuring a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways.

Firstly, by setting the path variable

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <Complete path of abc>)
```

Or by using relative imports.

Comment: I cannot mess with sys.path as the framework already does this. could you talk about the relative import method? I tried `from ..abc import settings` and ran it with `python -m` but I'm still getting an error

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

> The variable `sys.path` is a list of strings that determines the interpreter’s search path for modules. It is initialized to a default path taken from the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, or from a built-in default if `PYTHONPATH` is not set. You can modify it using standard list operations:

you need to add your root directory to `sys.path` :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_of_root')
```

Aldo `'..'+sys.path[0]` can give you the path of `abc` directory !